# Autohotkey Trim text with regular expression

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I have made an editor using Autohotkey (Version 1.0.48.05) and the HiEdit control. One function I a struggling to implement is trimming white space from a block of text - without deleting empty lines.

How can I stop the following REs deleting empty lines:

Block := RegExReplace(Block,"m)\s*$","")

Block := RegExReplace(Block,"m)^\s*","")

Many thanks in advance.

G

Dear Abdul,

Great [ \t] sorted my probem. I now know that \s matches EOL, where [ \t] or [:BLANK:] does not. Many thanks for your help

G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `[:blank:]` or `[ \t]` instead of `\s`.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a regular expression?

```
VarSetCapacity(fir, 20)  ; Ensure the variable is large enough to accept the new string.
fir.="text`nhello`n`n`n`n`n"

DllCall("Shlwapi.dll\StrTrim", "Str", fir, "Str", " `r`n",  "Cdecl")  ; Requires the Cdecl calling convention.
MsgBox, % fir
```

Seems to work as well